# Is it possible to detect if a process is trying to create a socket connection but the remote server refused

Tags: tcp, udp

Let's say that I have a process on my local Ubuntu. I want to know if it would use some socket connection(TCP or UDP) to connect some remote server, which has been turned off, meaning that any connection on it can't succeed.

In this case, is there some command ot some tool that allows me to detect if the process is trying to create some socket connection?

In other words, I hope some tool can tell me: the process is now trying to build a TCP/UDP connection with the remote server but it failed.

Comment: UDP is a connectionless protocol so, "UDP connection" is an oxymoron.  If you are trying to see what sockets are *current* open, netstat should work even if the other side hasn't responded.  If you need a retroactive log, you could set up a logging rule in your firewall.

Comment: or you could `strace` or similar the process and log the socket calls